# Using PHP Moodle filters to change one word to another?

Tags: php, filter, moodle

I've created this bit of code which converts the word colour to color:

```
<?php
class filter_helloworld extends moodle_text_filter {
public function filter($text, array $options = array()) {
    return str_replace('colour', 'color', $text);
}
}
?>
```

How would I make it so it can change multiple words, for example, I have a list of about 100 words to change from GB English to US English.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this, you can install the US language pack.

https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Language_packs

Go to site admin -> language -> language packs -> select "English - United Statues (en_us)"

You can set the default language to US English at site admin -> language -> language settings

Then any core strings will be displayed using US English.

Or a user can edit their profile and choose their preferred language.

If its text in a course that needs changing, then use the multi-lingual filter.

https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Multi-language_content_filter

So the course content would contain.

```
<span lang="en" class="multilang">colour</span>
<span lang="en_us" class="multilang">color</span>
```

Comment: filters are not applied to the language strings, they are applied to the contents that was input by the users

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'm sorry I should have been more specific as to why the filter is needed; the language changes need to be in the course content and there are hundreds and hundreds of pages on various science based subjects, so I don't really want to be editing every page if I can avoid it :/